# Finding all Sub ranges for a big range

Tags: algorithm

I have some files which are written between Start Time and End Time as follows;

[0 , 1] , [1,2] , [2 , 3] , [3, 4] , [4, 7] , [7, 8]

I want to find all the sub ranges for the time between 2 and 5 with O(N)

For above example;
[1,2] , [2 , 3] , [3, 4] , [4, 7]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _for the time between 2 and 5_ ?

Answer (score 1):

to my understanding of this question you would just compare each start/end time with 2 and 5 to check if they are within that range or not...

some pseudo code like:

```
if (StartTime >= 2 and StartTime <= 5) or (EndTime >=2 and EndTime <= 5)
    add this to your list of sub ranges.
```

you repeat for each element so it will be O(N)

Comment: It doesn't work if I have a single range [0, 8] and I am searching for file between 2 and 5